# How to remove NULLs and any wierd characters when exporing with nulls

Tags: hadoop, hive, null, beeline

I am able to extract data using Beeline into CSV or TSV.

But there are some NULLs and probably some other weird characters when dealing with a file to import it into database.

How to remove nulls/special characters from a file?
Or there is a Beeline command for that?

Thanks

Comment: you mean in files you have null or when you import the files you get null? same about weird characters

Comment: @GaurangShah - It seems that is in file. When I try to import - it complains about it..

Comment: I think nulls you are getting becuause there is a datatype mismatch and weird character because of encoding mismtach.